# how can we edit an xml file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, dom

I have loaded one xml file using activeX or xmlDom.

Now I can iterate through the element and read the values.

But how can I edit the values inside the elements?

for example `<name>big fat pig </name>` to `<name>some other pig</name>`.

All these must be done purely in javascript and no JQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

you have your DOM in memory, right?
in this case you should just use your dom API available from Java Script and modify it.
How to do that?

An example:
[Google Result 1](http://acsummer.wordpress.com/2007/12/23/dynamically-modifying-the-dom-with-javascript-cd-collection-app-post-01/)

Hope, this helps

Comment: You are right the xml is in the DOM memory, everythings is working fine.

Comment: But I want to update a single element's inner content using pure javascript

Comment: The tutorial shows how to append Child elements and how to create new elements inside the existing elements

Comment: I guess, nodeValue property should be updated, look here http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml